# edited hosts file and now localhost doesnt work

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, hosts

So I was trying to add an entry to my hosts file so that my testing environment would be at local.domain.com instead of localhost.

Now that I made edits, nothing is working, including localhost. I read somewhere that it has something to do with editing it in certain programs giving weird errors so to open it in something else and save it. I tried that and still nothing.

Is there any way i can just 'reset' this file? Or any ideas anyone has?

Answer (score 1):

did You try this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

Comment: I did not, what does that do? i ended up just deleting the file and retyping it out in vim, and that worked fine

Comment: i'm not a pro (at least @ MAC ^^), but AFAIK that the 2 entries above are defining the localhost to `127.0.0.1` (IPv4 protocol) and to `::1` (IPv6 protocol). so, IMHO if You deleted Your hosts file, Your machine doesn't find the localhost destination...